# Does my *Entire* game have to be remade, to use Cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have been making my game in a pretty conventional manner. I just created a new window based application and have built off of that using my own images, table views, etc. Now I am about to begin programming the gameplay, and I just recently discovered Cocos2D. My question is this: In order to use Cocos2D for the actual gameplay (Which would take place in a single view) do I need to recreate my app from scratch? Or can I just make the one view using Cocos2D?

Answer (score 2):

You could go down the mix-and-match route, but it would likely drive you insane.

If you want to embrace Cocos2D, you will likely be better off moving to it fully.   More likely than not the time invested will be yield improvements in your existing code that you'll find surprising (certainly, I've found that rewriting something pretty much always yields a better solution in fewer lines of code).

Comment: I agree that the mix-match route is definitely possible (done it before), but that it might be better to go full-Cocos2D if you have the time and willingness. It will definitely save you some headaches in the end.

Comment: thank You! I really appreciate it. I will get started immediately and hopefully have my app out in a few weeks. Assuming I can pick up on Cocos2D quickly enough.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to keep using the standard SDK in your game, if you're going to use Cocos2D for the game view (which you totally should).

Re-do the entire app in Cocos2D -- you'll have way more possibilities to make your game menus awesome and **much** less headaches; both while developing and while maintaining your game.